# Does Azure Storage Data Movement Library support Azure Tables?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I want to create blob from Azure Table. AzCopy supports this functionality but I couldn't find any document stating that Data movement API also supports it.
IS this option available ?

> https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-storage-data-movement-library-preview-2/

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Azure Storage Data Movement Library doesn't support Azure Storage Table.

Comment: Does my reply solve your question? If my reply is helpful, please mark it as answer, which will help others find and resolve similar problem quickly.

Comment: And here we are in 2020 still don't have a decent backup strategy for azure table storage. Thanks Microsoft...